# How to define global variables based on rules on gitlabci?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How to define global variables based on rules on gitlabci?

I have a syntax error with this script and I wonder how to fix it. My goal is to use different environment variables based on my branch.

Is it possible to define once a list of environment variables for the two stages (build and deploy)?

If not how can I reduce and simplify my script to avoid redundancy? I tested anchors but the possibility to define global environment variables for all my script based on my branch would be really awesome!

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == /develop/
    variables:
      BUILD_ENV: "build:staging"
      CLUSTER_NAME: "STAGING"
      SERVICE_NAME: "WebappSTAGING"
      TASK_DEFINITION_NAME: "FlaskSTAGING"
      S3_BUCKET_URL: ""
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == /master/
    variables:
      BUILD_ENV: "build"
      CLUSTER_NAME: ""
      SERVICE_NAME: ""
      TASK_DEFINITION_NAME: ""
      S3_BUCKET_URL: ""


image: docker:19.03.10
#image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-ecs:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - IMAGE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
  - pip install awscli
  - pip install ecs-deploy
  - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $REPOSITORY_URL

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_container:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building Flask image..."
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URL/flask:$IMAGE_TAG ./Flask_server
    - echo "Tagging Flask image..."
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URL/flask:$IMAGE_TAG $REPOSITORY_URL/flask:$IMAGE_TAG
    - echo "Pushing Flask image..."
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URL/flask:$IMAGE_TAG
  only:
    - develop
    - master

build_staticfiles:
  stage: build
  image: node:14
  before_script:
    - nodejs -v
    - npm -v
  script:
    - cd client
    - npm install
    - npm run $BUILD_ENV
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - client/dist/
    expire_in: 30 minutes
  only:
    - develop
    - master


deploy_container:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo $REPOSITORY_URL/flask:$IMAGE_TAG
    - ecs deploy $CLUSTER_NAME $SERVICE_NAME --timeout -1
  only:
    - develop
    - master

deploy_static_files:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - aws s3 cp client/dist/ S3_BUCKET_URL --recursive
  only:
    - develop
    - master
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your rules under the global `workflow` keyword to get rid of the syntax error. With this settings pipelines are only created if the commit branch is develop or master and the variables should be set accordingly.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == /develop/
      variables:
        BUILD_ENV: "build:staging"
        CLUSTER_NAME: "STAGING"
        SERVICE_NAME: "WebappSTAGING"
        TASK_DEFINITION_NAME: "FlaskSTAGING"
        S3_BUCKET_URL: ""
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == /master/
      variables:
        BUILD_ENV: "build"
        CLUSTER_NAME: ""
        SERVICE_NAME: ""
        TASK_DEFINITION_NAME: ""
        S3_BUCKET_URL: ""
```

Comment: hi, where do you put workflow? inside each job? because putting it outside does not work. i got empty variable for example BUILD_ENV.